# how to run .c files containing complex.h in linux

Tags: bash, gcc

I can compile a file using gcc -o zipcode-server filename.c -lm. But when I tried to run the file using ./filename it shows "bash: ./filename: No such file or directory". Any help will be useful. Thanks in advance

Comment: The file you should run is `./zipcode-server` since this is what is specified with the `-o` switch

Comment: You *do* know what the `-o` option to `gcc` does, don't you?

Comment: thanks.@Cyclone  and @Joachim Pileborg   ./zipcode-server works

Comment: @KrishanuPal - If any of the answers helped you consider marking it as correct and perhaps give it an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `o` flag which in turn specifies where to store the output. In your case the `-o zipcode-server` tells the compiler to store the output in a file called `zipcode-server`:

```
./zipcode-server
```

Comment: @KrishanuPal - If the answer helped you consider accepting it and perhaps give it an upvote =)

Answer (score 0):

gcc filename.c

./a.out

Second Method

gcc filename.c -o outputfile

./outputfile